# Doubly linked, cyclic list in standard library

Tags: c++, linked-list, std

I need doubly linked cyclic list, but a cant find it in STL containers (singly linked cyclic list too).

It may looks like that:

```
element 0   <->   element 1  <-> ... <-> ...

    ^                                     ^
    |                                     |
    v                                     v

element n   <->   element n-1   <->   element n-2
```

Can you show me what i missed? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You haven't missed anything. There is no such container in the standard library.

Comment: How would you iterate over a cyclic list with the STL? Would you expect it to loop infinitly?

Comment: No. Only one cycle from start element.

Comment: Doubly linked lists **are useful** patterns for a lot of well defined use cases in general. Though I wouldn't want them to be cyclic, without knowing if I'm at `head` or `tail`. Usually I let the `previous` pointer for a `head` node point to `NULL` and the `next` pointer of the tail accordingly. This makes any operation implementations a lot easier.

Comment: Linear list useful in one case, cycle list in another case.
It's different patterns. In my case it is doesn't matter where HEAD.

Comment: @StepanLoginov I meant STL standard operations, like `push_back()`, etc. pp.

Answer (score 5):

You haven't missed anything. There is no such container in the standard library.